# Does absolute and uniform convergence imply normal convergence?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f_n$ be a sequence of holomorphic functions defined on some compact set $K$ in $\mathbb C$ (i.e. each function in the sequence is holomorphic on some nbd of $K$).

If $\sum f_n$ converges uniformly and absolutely on $K$ then can we say it coverges normally on $K$ (i.e $\sum \Vert f_n\Vert$ is finite)?

Note- It’s very easy to construct counterexamples for smooth functions using bump functions.

I am curious about this because in J. B. Conway’s *Complex Analysis* book, in one lemma (Lemma 5.8, Chapter 7) needed for Weierstrass factorization theorem, he states uniform and absolute convergence in the hypothesis but uses normal convergence in the proof.

Comment: I don't think that Conway uses $\sum \|f_n\|_\infty < \infty.$ I think he uses the uniform convergence of  $\sum |f_n|,$ which is still an error.

Comment: True! But normal convergence is easy to state as well as less confusing so I used that in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can also construct counterexamples using holomorphic functions. Let $K$ be the closed unit disk, define $\zeta_n = \exp(i/n)$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}$, and $h(z) = \frac{1}{2}(1 + z)$. Choose positive integers $m_n$ such that
$$\lvert h(z)\rvert^{m_n} \leqslant 2^{-n}$$
for all $z \in K$ with $\lvert z-1\rvert \geqslant \frac{1}{10n^2}$ and put
$$f_n(z) = \frac{1}{n}h(\zeta_n z)^{m_n}\,.$$
Then $\lVert f_n\rVert = \frac{1}{n}$, so the series is not normally convergent on $K$. But it is absolutely and uniformly convergent on $K$. For every $z \in K$, we have $\lvert f_n(z)\rvert \leqslant 2^{-n}$ for all but at most one $n$, so
$$\sum_{n = m}^{\infty} \lvert f_n(z)\rvert \leqslant \frac{1}{m} + \sum_{n = m}^{\infty} 2^{-n} = \frac{1}{m} + 2^{1-m}\,.$$

Comment: Thanks. Does that means lemma I mentioned is wrongly proved in Conway’s book? I was curious because Conway’s book is tried and tested for 3-4 decades. How can nobody got this gap in the argument?

Comment: I don't know, I don't have Conway's book at hand. It may be an error in Conway's proof. But Weierstraß's theorem is correct, so if it's an error, it's not catastrophic.

Comment: True. In other complex analysis books, above lemma has been given with normal convergence in the hypothesis which is sufficient for weierstrass theorem. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

This is not as good an answer as Daniel Fischer's, but I include it because it's not too much different from the $C^\infty$ bump function idea that you mentioned.

Choose pairwise disjoint closed intervals $[a_n,b_n],n=1,2,\dots$ contained in $[0,1].$ For each $n,$ choose a continuous $f_n$ on $[0,1],$ with support $[a_n,b_n],$ such that $\|f_n\|=1/n.$ Then $\sum f_n$ converges uniformly on $[0,1].$

By the Weierstrass approximation theorem, there exist polynomials $p_n$ such that $\|p_n-f_n\|<1/2^n.$ Claim: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}p_n$ has the desired property on $K=[0,1].$

Proof of claim: For each $x\in [0,1],$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|p_n(x)| \le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|p_n(x)-f_n(x)| + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|f_n(x)| <\infty.$$

So $\sum p_n$ converges absolutely on $[0,1].$ Given $M<N,$ we have

$$|\sum_{M}^{N}p_n(x)| \le |\sum_{M}^{N}(p_n(x)-f_n(x))|+|\sum_{M}^{N}f_n(x)|,\,\, x\in [0,1].$$

This implies the partial sums of $\sum p_n$ are uniformly Cauchy on $[0,1],$ hence $\sum p_n$ converges uniformly on $[0,1].$ Since $\sum \|f_n\| = \infty,$ the claim is proved.

Comment: Nice! Your proof gives counterexample for real analytic function on compact subset of $\mathbb R$

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is relevant for you: In Remmert's excellent book *Theory of Complex Functions*, he says on page 106 in the section on normal convergence:

> If $X$ is a locally compact metric space and $\sum \| f_\nu \|_K < \infty $ for every compactum $K$ in $X$, then $\sum f_\nu$ is normally convergent in $X$.

Comment: I think here normal convergence stands for something else otherwise just consider $\sum z^n$ on unit disc in $\mathbb C$

Comment: He defines normal convergence as (see page 104): "A series $\sum f_\nu$ of functions $f: X \to \mathbb{C}$ is called *normally convergent* in $X$ if each point $x \in X$ has a neighborhood $U \subseteq X$ which satisfies $\sum \| f_\nu \|_U < \infty$."

Comment: Yes....but what I want is different.